# What is the point of these virtual tables?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

If I import a schema using entity framework, my tables get some `virtual ICollection` tables added to them if they have foreign key links on other tables. E.g.:

```
Table1
Id | ColumnA

Table2
Id | Table1Id_fk | ColumnZ
```

where `Table1` will import as this model:

```
public class Table1
{
    public Table1()
    {
        Table2s = new HashSet<Table2>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ColumnA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2s { get; set; } // added because of the fk on Table2
}
```

This also then comes through if I serialise my objects as a string response so I can see an empty `Table2s : []` in there, I'm wondering if it has something to do with that, but my main questions is

Why does this happen? What's the point? I can remove them and it doesn't stop working, so far it's just cluttering my code because I don't know what they're for :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically convenience provided to you by Entity Framework. This way in your code you can treat foreign key relationships as simple properties without having to do the join yourself.

If you remove these virtual properties, you'll have to connect the entities yourself.

Getting all `Table2` items related to `Table1`

- with virtual property:

  ```
  var allTable2s = table1Item.Table2s;
  ```
- without:

  ```
  var allTable2s = dbContext.Table2s.Where(t2 => t2.Table1Id == table1Item.Id);
  ```

You should also have a look at the Entity Framework documentation: [Understanding Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you're using EF Core, and if it became the standard there when you're scaffolding your models.
But:

Sometimes you need virtual Collections, to *reference* another Entity, avoiding that EF re-creates that entity over and over.

Imagine you have a table with `Cars`.

Theres also a table with `Vignettes`.

Imagine one of your `Car's` properties is a Collection of `Vignettes`.

If you were to retrieve 2 `Vignettes` from your `Vignette` table and set them as the vignettes on your `Car`, EF by default will assume that the vignettes are new Entities, and will create them in the database for you. This can be, to put it in nice words ... ***undesirable***.

Now, if you make your Collection virtual, this suddenly becomes a Navigation Property for EF. It tells EF,

> "hey, I would only like the references for the vignettes on this
>   entity"

So when you queue the object from your EF context, EF will get all the info of the entity, and then go look for your referenced entities (the vignettes in this case) and stuff them into your Car entity.

It also enables EF's lazy loading mechanic for that Collection.